How to Remap Kernel to Virtual Address 0xC0000000 in My Paging Setup?
I'm working on implementing paging for my custom 32-bit kernel. Currently, my kernel is loaded at the physical address 0x100000 (1MB), and I want to remap it to the virtual address 0xC0000000 after enabling paging. This is a common practice in kernel development to separate the kernel's virtual memory space from the user space.
I already have the paging set up in my kernel, including page directory and page tables, and some basic functions like:

extern uint32_t page_directory[1024];
extern uint32_t first_page_table[1024];
void init_paging();
void load_page_directory(uint32_t page_directory_address);
void enable_paging();

Here is a summary of my code so far:
paging.c:
#include "../Includes/paging.h"

uint32_t page_directory[1024] __attribute__((aligned(4096)));
uint32_t first_page_table[1024] __attribute__((aligned(4096)));

// Set up the first page table, first 4MB of memory (identity mapping)
void init_paging() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        first_page_table[i] = (i * PAGE_SIZE) | PAGE_PRESENT | PAGE_WRITABLE;
    }

    page_directory[0] = ((uint32_t)first_page_table) | PAGE_PRESENT | PAGE_WRITABLE;

    // Map virtual address 0xC0000000 to physical address 0x100000
    page_directory[768] = ((uint32_t)first_page_table) | PAGE_PRESENT | PAGE_WRITABLE;

    load_page_directory((uint32_t)page_directory);

    // Enable paging by setting the PG bit in CR0
    enable_paging();
}

void load_page_directory(uint32_t page_directory_address) {
    __asm__ volatile("mov %0, %%cr3" :: "r"(page_directory_address));
}

void enable_paging() {
    uint32_t cr0;
    __asm__ volatile("mov %%cr0, %0" : "=r"(cr0));
    cr0 |= 0x80000000;  // Set the paging (PG) bit
    __asm__ volatile("mov %0, %%cr0" :: "r"(cr0));
}

The paging works fine for identity mapping, but I'm not sure how to correctly remap my kernel's code to run at 0xC0000000 instead of 0x100000. I know that I need to update my linker script and paging setup to handle this properly, but I'm having trouble understanding how to do this in practice.
Here are my questions:

How can I modify my linker script (linker.ld) to link the kernel at virtual address 0xC0000000 while it is physically loaded at 0x100000?
How should I modify my paging setup to map the physical address 0x100000 to the virtual address 0xC0000000?
Are there any additional steps or considerations for making sure my kernel functions properly after the remapping (e.g., updating segment registers, ensuring correct access)?

Below is my current linker script:
ENTRY(_start)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x100000;
    
    .text : {
        *(.entry) /* Ensure .entry section is always first */
        *(.text*)
    }

    .rodata : {
        *(.rodata*)
    }

    .data : {
        *(.data)
    }

    .bss : {
        *(.bss)
    }
}

Any help on how to achieve this remapping would be greatly appreciated!
if needed here is my repository with full code https://github.com/IlanVinograd/OS_32Bit
kernel.c:
#include "../Includes/kernel.h"

void _start(void) {
    init_idt();  // Initialize the IDT
    init_paging();  // Initialize paging system

    clearScreen();
    setCursorPosition(0, 0);
    initScreen("0.3");

    /*
    You can uncomment the following ISR code and test it yourself.
    */

    /*
    // Trigger Divide by Zero Exception (ISR0)
    int a = 10;
    int b = 0;
    int c = a / b;
    */

    /*
    // Trigger Invalid Opcode Exception (ISR6)
    asm volatile ("ud2");
    */

    /*
    // Test General Protection Fault (ISR13)
    asm volatile ("int $13");  // This will trigger ISR13
    */

    /*
    // Test Page Fault (ISR14) - This will only work if paging is enabled
    uint32_t *ptr = (uint32_t*)0xFFFFFFFF;  // Invalid address
    uint32_t data = *ptr;  // Dereference invalid memory (triggers ISR14)
    */

    while (1);  // Loop indefinitely
}

paging.h:
#ifndef _PAGING_H_
#define _PAGING_H_

#include <stdint.h>
#include <io.h>

extern uint32_t page_directory[1024];
extern uint32_t first_page_table[1024];

#define PAGE_SIZE 4096  // Size of each page (4KB)

// Define bit flags for the entries in page directory/table
#define PAGE_PRESENT    0x1  // Page is present in memory
#define PAGE_WRITABLE   0x2  // Page is writable
#define PAGE_USER       0x4  // Page is accessible in user mode

// Page directory and page table entry structure
typedef uint32_t page_directory_entry_t;
typedef uint32_t page_table_entry_t;

void init_paging();
void load_page_directory(uint32_t page_directory_address);
void enable_paging();

#endif /* _PAGING_H_ */

kernel.h:
#ifndef KERNEL_H
#define KERNEL_H

#include <paging.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <vga.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <idt.h>

#endif

stage2.asm:
[BITS 16]
[org 0x8000]

; Kernel sectors to read
KERNEL_SECTORS     equ 0x0f
KERNEL_LOAD_SEG    equ 0x1000
KERNEL_LOAD_OFFSET equ 0x0000
KERNEL_LOAD_ADDR   equ  ((KERNEL_LOAD_SEG<<4) + KERNEL_LOAD_OFFSET)
KERNEL_RUN_ADDR    equ 0x100000

TSS_ADDR_HI_BYTE_OFFSET equ 5
TSS_ACCESS_BYTE_OFFSET  equ 7

jmp a20_enable

; -------------------------
; BSS Section for TSS
; -------------------------
section .bss
tss resb 104    ; Reserve 104 bytes for the TSS (Task State Segment)

; -------------------------
; Initialize the TSS
; -------------------------
section .text
 
init_tss:
    ; Set ESP0 (stack pointer for privilege level 0)
    mov eax, 0x9FC00        ; Example stack pointer for ring 0
    mov [tss + 4], eax      ; Set ESP0 in the TSS
 
    ; Set SS0 (stack segment for privilege level 0)
    mov ax, 0x10            ; Kernel data segment selector (0x10)
    mov [tss + 8], ax       ; Set SS0 in the TSS
 
    ; Swap the byte with tss address bits 24:31 with the access byte
    ; In the TSS descriptor
    mov al, [gdt.tss + TSS_ADDR_HI_BYTE_OFFSET]
    xchg al, [gdt.tss + TSS_ACCESS_BYTE_OFFSET]
    mov [gdt.tss + TSS_ADDR_HI_BYTE_OFFSET], al
 
    ret                     ; Return to the main flow

; -------------------------
; A20 Enable
; -------------------------
a20_enable:
    pushf               ; Save flags
    push dx             ; Save DX register with boot drive
    push ds             ; Save data segment
    push es             ; Save extra segment
    push di             ; Save destination index
    push si             ; Save source index

    cli

    in al, 0x92
    or al, 2
    out 0x92, al

; -------------------------
; A20 Enable Msg
; -------------------------
status_a20_on:
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov ah, 0x0E         ; Set up for character output
    mov bh, 0x00         ; Display page number

    mov si, msg_a20_enable ; Load success message into SI

print_enable_loop:
    lodsb                ; Load next byte from message
    cmp al, 0            ; Check for null terminator
    je restore_registers_a20 ; If end of string, restore registers
    int 0x10             ; Print character in AL
    jmp print_enable_loop ; Loop to print the next character

restore_registers_a20:
    pop si               ; Restore source index
    pop di               ; Restore destination index
    pop es               ; Restore extra segment
    pop ds               ; Restore data segment
    pop dx               ; Restore DX register
    popf                 ; Restore flags
 
    sti                  ; Re-enable interrupts

; -------------------------
; Load kernel from disk
; -------------------------
    mov ax, KERNEL_LOAD_SEG
                        ; Load 0x1000 (segment for 1MB) into AX
    mov es, ax          ; Move AX (0x1000) into ES
    mov bx, KERNEL_LOAD_OFFSET
                        ; Offset within the segment

    mov ah, 02h         ; BIOS Interrupt 13h, Function 02h: Read sectors from the disk.
    mov al, KERNEL_SECTORS
                        ; Read 1 sector from the disk (this corresponds to the size of a sector, which is 512 bytes).

    mov ch, 00h         ; Set Cylinder number to 0 (since both Stage 1 and Stage 2 are on Cylinder 0).
    mov cl, 03h         ; Set Sector number to 2 (Stage 1 is in Sector 1, so Stage 2 starts at Sector 2).
    mov dh, 00h         ; Set Head number to 0 (assuming we are using Head 0 for now).

    int 13h

    jmp gdt_setup

; -------------------------
; GDT Setup and TSS Setup
; -------------------------
gdt_setup:
    cli
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor] ; Load GDT descriptor into GDTR

    push ds
    push es
 
    call init_tss         ; Initialize the TSS
 
    pop es
    pop ds

; -------------------------
; GDT & TSS Success Message
; -------------------------
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov ah, 0x0E         ; Set up for character output
    mov bh, 0x00         ; Display page number

    mov si, msg_gdtss_success ; Load GDT success message into SI

gdtss_print_success:
    lodsb                   ; Load next byte from message
    cmp al, 0               ; Check for null terminator
    je enter_protected_mode     ; If end of string, proceed to protected mode
    int 0x10                ; Print character in AL
    jmp gdtss_print_success   ; Loop to print the next character

; -------------------------
; Enter Protected Mode
; -------------------------
enter_protected_mode:
    cli                 ; Disable interrupts before entering protected mode

    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1           ; Set protected mode bit in CR0
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp 0x08:update_segments
; -------------------------
; Protected Mode Code Segment
; -------------------------
[BITS 32]
update_segments:
    cli
    
    mov ax, 0x10        ; Load GDT data segment selector (0x10)
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000
    mov esp, ebp

    mov ax, 0x28          ; TSS selector
    ltr ax                ; Load Task Register with TSS selector

; -------------------------
; Kernel Code
; -------------------------
kernel:
    ; Copy the kernel from 0x10000 to 0x100000
    cld
    mov esi, KERNEL_LOAD_ADDR
    mov edi, KERNEL_RUN_ADDR
    mov ecx, KERNEL_SECTORS * 512
    rep movsb

    jmp 0x08:KERNEL_RUN_ADDR

; -------------------------
; GDT Descriptor and TSS
; -------------------------
section .data
gdt_start:
gdt:
     ; Null Descriptor
    dd 0x0
    dd 0x0
 
    ; Kernel Code Segment (DPL = 0)
    dw 0xFFFF              ; Limit
    dw 0x0000              ; Base (lower 16 bits)
    db 0x00                ; Base (next 8 bits)
    db 10011010b           ; Access byte
    db 11001111b           ; Flags and limit (upper 4 bits)
    db 0x00                ; Base (upper 8 bits)
 
    ; Kernel Data Segment (DPL = 0)
    dw 0xFFFF              ; Limit
    dw 0x0000              ; Base (lower 16 bits)
    db 0x00                ; Base (next 8 bits)
    db 10010010b           ; Access byte
    db 11001111b           ; Flags and limit (upper 4 bits)
    db 0x00                ; Base (upper 8 bits)
 
    ; User Code Segment (DPL = 3)
    dw 0xFFFF              ; Limit
    dw 0x0000              ; Base (lower 16 bits)
    db 0x00                ; Base (next 8 bits)
    db 11111010b           ; Access byte (DPL = 3)
    db 11001111b           ; Flags and limit (upper 4 bits)
    db 0x00                ; Base (upper 8 bits)
 
    ; User Data Segment (DPL = 3)
    dw 0xFFFF              ; Limit
    dw 0x0000              ; Base (lower 16 bits)
    db 0x00                ; Base (next 8 bits)
    db 11110010b           ; Access byte (DPL = 3)
    db 11001111b           ; Flags and limit (upper 4 bits)
    db 0x00                ; Base (upper 8 bits)
 
    ; TSS Descriptor
.tss:
    dw 0x0067                   ; Limit
    dd tss                      ; Base
    db 00000000b                ; Flags and limit (upper 4 bits)
    db 10001001b                ; Access byte
 
gdt_end:
 
; GDT Descriptor (contains size and location of GDT)
gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1  ; Size of the GDT (in bytes, minus 1)
    dd gdt_start

; -------------------------
; Messages
; -------------------------
msg_a20_enable  db 'A20 line enable                 ->   successfully ', 0x0D, 0x0A, 0

msg_gdtss_success db 'GDT and TSS is configured       ->   successfully ', 0x0D, 0x0A, 0


stage1.asm:
[BITS 16]               ; We are working in 16-bit Real Mode
[org 0x7c00]            ; The origin (starting address) of the bootloader in memory, which is 0x7C00 as loaded by the BIOS.
                        ; This is the physical address where the bootloader is loaded into memory.
start:                  ; Start of execution, this label marks the entry point of the code.
    jmp 0x0000:main            ; Jump to the 'main' label to start execution.

main:                   ; Main routine of the bootloader begins here.

; -------------------------
; Setup segment registers
; -------------------------
    cld                 ; Set direction forward (DF=0) for string instructions (STOS, LODS, CMPS etc)
    cli                 ; Clear interrupts to ensure no interrupts occur while setting up segments.
    xor ax, ax          ; Set AX to 0x0 (which is 0x0 >> 4).
                        ; Explanation: We are using segment:offset addressing in real mode.
                        ; Physical address = Segment * 16 + Offset
                        ; So, the segment 0x0 * 16 = 0x0 (physical address).
    mov ds, ax          ; Set Data Segment (DS) to 0x0. DS points to the bootloader code/data in memory.
    mov es, ax          ; Set Extra Segment (ES) to 0x0. ES is also set to point to our code/data.

; -------------------------
; Setup stack
; -------------------------
    mov ss, ax          ; Set Stack Segment (SS) to 0 (base of memory).
    mov sp, 0xFFFE      ; Set the Stack Pointer (SP) to the highest address within the current 64KB segment (0x0000:0xFFFE).
                        ; In real mode, the stack grows downward from 0xFFFE and 0xFFFE should be set to an even offset like 0xFFFE, not an odd one.
    push dx             ; Save the DL register with the boot drive
    sti                 ; Re-enable interrupts after segment and stack setup is complete.

; -------------------------
; Load Stage 2 bootloader from disk
; -------------------------
    mov ah, 02h         ; BIOS Interrupt 13h, Function 02h: Read sectors from the disk.
    mov al, 01h         ; Read 1 sector from the disk (this corresponds to the size of a sector, which is 512 bytes).

    mov ch, 00h         ; Set Cylinder number to 0 (since both Stage 1 and Stage 2 are on Cylinder 0).
    mov cl, 02h         ; Set Sector number to 2 (Stage 1 is in Sector 1, so Stage 2 starts at Sector 2).
    mov dh, 00h         ; Set Head number to 0 (assuming we are using Head 0 for now).
    mov dl, 80h         ; Use the first hard drive (usually 0x80 for the primary hard disk).

    mov bx, 0x8000      ; Set BX to 0x8000, the offset address where Stage 2 will be loaded.
                        ; Stage 2 will be loaded into memory using segment:offset addressing.
                        ; ES = 0x0, BX = 0x8000, so the physical address = ES * 16 + BX.
                        ; Formula: 0x0 * 16 + 0x8000 = 0x0 + 0x8000 = 0x8000 (the physical address where Stage 2 is loaded).

    int 13h             ; Call BIOS interrupt 13h to read the specified sectors into memory.

    jc disk_read_error  ; If carry flag is set (indicating an error), jump to the error handler.

pass:                   ; If the disk read was successful (carry flag is cleared), continue from here.
    pop dx              ; Restore the DL register containing the boot drive in DL
    jmp 0x0000:0x8000   ; Jump to the loaded Stage 2 at address 0x0000:0x8000 (this is where Stage 2 resides).
                        ; Here, 0x0000 is the segment, and 0x8000 is the offset.
                        ; Physical address = 0x0000 * 16 + 0x8000 = 0x8000, where Stage 2 is loaded.

disk_read_error:
    int 18h             ; If the disk read fails, call INT 18h to attempt a boot from a different device (like network boot).
                        ; This error message will occur --> IO write(0x01f0): current command is 20h displayed on bochs emulator.

TIMES 510-($-$$) DB 0   ; Pad the bootloader to ensure it is exactly 512 bytes, with zeros filling the remaining space.
DW 0xAA55               ; The boot signature (magic number) required for the BIOS to recognize this as a bootable sector.

kernel_entry.s:

.section .entry, "ax"
.extern _start

_entry:
    call _start

hltloop:
    hlt
    jmp hltloop




I was unaware you posted a question here. Earlier today I put in a pull request with fixes to get this going.https://github.com/IlanVinograd/OS_32Bit/pull/34
